# How do i split this array into two?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array.

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [isRequired] => 1
            [isBetween] => 1
            [isAlphaLower] => 
            [isLength] => 
        )

    [email] => Array
        (
            [isEmail] => 1
        )

    [pPhone] => Array
        (
            [isPhone] => 
        )

)
```

i want to split the array into two.

**1. array with all boolean value true**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [isRequired] => 1
            [isBetween] => 1
        )

    [email] => Array
        (
            [isEmail] => 1
        )

)
```

**2. array with all boolean value false**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [isAlphaLower] => 
            [isLength] => 
        )

    [pPhone] => Array
        (
            [isPhone] => 
        )
)
```

How do i do it?

thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. initialize the two new arrays
2. foreach the input array
3. foreach the inner array of each input array entry
4. according to the value set the one or the other of the two new arrays
5. done.

Example:

```
$arrayTrue = $arrayFalse = arrray(); # 1
foreach($arrayInput as $baseKey => $inner) # 2
    foreach($inner as $key => $value) # 3
        if ($value) $arrayTrue[$basekey][$key] = $value; # 4
        else $arrayFalse[$basekey][$key] = $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function is_true($var) {
    return $var;
}
function is_false($var) {
    return !$var;
}

$result_true = array();
$result_false = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $a) {
    $result_true[$k] = array_filter($a, 'is_true');
    $result_false[$k] = array_filter($a, 'is_false');
};
```

or

```
$result_true = array();
$result_false = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $a) {
    $result_true[$k] = array_filter($a);
    $result_false[$k] = array_filter($a, function ($x) { return !$x; } );
};
```

Comment: note: is there a builtin identity and negate function in PHP that I can use? it's quite a basic thing for functional programming..

Comment: If no callback is supplied for `array_filter`, all entries of input equal to FALSE will be removed. So the `is_true` is not necessary.

Comment: @xdazz: the `is_true` is not required but I already fixed that by the time you posted it.

Answer (score 0):

As your array is a 2 level array, you will need to use 2 loops.

```
$trueValues = array();
$falseValues = array();
foreach($input AS $key=>$firstLevelValue) {
    foreach($firstLevelValue AS $key2=>$secondLevelValue)  {
        if ($secondLevelValue)
            $trueValues[$key][$key2] = $secondLevelValue;
        else
            $falseValues[$key][$key2] = $secondLevelValue;
    }
}
```

A 3 level array would be:

```
$trueValues = array();
$falseValues = array();
foreach($input AS $key=>$firstLevelValue) {
    foreach($firstLevelValue AS $key2=>$secondLevelValue)  {
        foreach($secondLevelValue AS $key3=>$thirdLevelValue)  {
            if ($thirdLevelValue)
                $trueValues[$key][$key2][$key3] = $thirdLevelValue;
            else
                $falseValues[$key][$key2][$key3] = $thirdLevelValue;
        }
    }
}
```